# How do I set the mime type of a request made by Dart's HttpRequest in my web app?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I want to send an AJAX request with Dart. I want the body of that request to be URL encoded, just like a form submit. I want to set the mime type to indicate this. How do I do it?

I tried setting `mimeType` on the request, but that did not help.

Here's the code:

```dart
HttpRequest.request(url,
  mimeType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  sendData: myUrlEncodedString);
```

Comment: Isn't this a bug when there is an option that doesn't work?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer not sure?

Comment: If it looks like a bug it probably is one ;-) You could file a bug and look what response you get (or just ask).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `mimeType`, instead use `requestHeaders`. Here's an example:

```dart
HttpRequest.request(url,
  requestHeaders: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  sendData: 'hello=world&welcome=todart');
```